# Table Cell Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table. When I click on the cell segue should be performed. I try to use `prepareForSegue` and `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but without any result. 
My code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {

            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"OpenB"]){

                OpenBViewController *controller = (OpenBViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
                controller.address = self.selectedCellText;
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenB" sender:self];
            }
    }
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            self.selectedCellText = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenB" sender:self];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: Delete `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenB" sender:self];` in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Does you code go through the methods? Any Breakpoints or NSLog ?

Comment: My code goes through cellforRowIndexPath only. I create new segue, rewrite my code, but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenB" sender:self];` inside of `-prepareForSegue:` method because `-prepareForSegue` is called when segue is about to be performed.

Second, check that you have your segue setup correctly. Make sure you have provided the same identifier to the segue in the storyboard that you are using with `-performSegueWithIdentifier:`

Comment: It doesn't work. I checked all identifiers, delete [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenB" sender:self];

Comment: Is your `-prepareForSegue:` getting called after you call perform `-performSegueWithIdentifier:` in tableview's -didSelectRow method? Also try deleting the segue from storyboard and create a new one and assign it a different identifier. Also change your code to use that identifier.

Comment: calling only cellForRorIndexPath function

Comment: What do you mean by "calling only cellForRorIndexPath function"? is `-didSelectRow` not getting called? If that's the case, your table view's delegate property is not set. If `-didSelectRow` method is called (including `-performSegueWithIdentifier`) but not the `-prepareForSegue:`, there is something wrong in your story board setup.

Comment: I create new table view and this helped me

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as follows:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"OpenB"]){

        OpenBViewController *controller = (OpenBViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.address = self.selectedCellText;
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    self.selectedCellText = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenB" sender:self];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

And keep in mind to setup a segue with identifier `OpenB` in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just leaving this here in case it happens to someone else.

Also, all code is in Swift 3, because my knowledge of Objective C syntax is next to nil.

The problem was most likely that the `didSelectRow()` method gets called ***after*** the segue was pushed. So when the `prepare(ForSegue)` one gets called, the `selectedTextCell` variable has not been properly initialized.

If you're connecting from the cell to the next ViewController via a segue created in the Interface Builder, you don't need to use `didSelectRow()` and probably you shouldn't, because the segue is likely to be always pushed before `didSelectRow()`.

In that case, all you need to do is retrieve the information from the cell in the `prepare()` method.

The signature is:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

The sender is whichever object triggers the segue. In this case, the cell that was selected. So, in prepare(), you would write something like this:

```
let myCell = sender as! UITableViewCell
controller.address = myCell.textLabel.text
```

If you need to access the row, for example, it would be:

```
controller.idx = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)?.row
```

Of course, UITableViewCell can be replaced by any custom Cell class you may have.